# JTable renderer with sorting

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I am trying to sort a table using rowsorter.

```
RowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
cTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

I am using a renderer which extends DefaultTableCellRenderer. I am using the renderer to paint the contents of the cell in some color based on its value.

```
cTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class,new <renderer name>());
```

eg:

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object v,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {

         super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, v, isSelected, hasFocus,
                    row, column);
int k=table.getValueAt(row,column);
    if (k >= 0)                             this.setForeground(Color.red);
}
```

Note:This is just a sample code.No real functionality.
when i sort, sorting happens perfectly but the renderer functionality of changing the color is not happening. Has anyone faced this issue earlier?Please help

Answer (score 4):

You need to extend the logic in your renderer to:

```
if (isSelected) {
  this.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
} else if (k >= 0) {
  this.setForeground(Color.red);
} else {
  this.setForeground(table.getForegroundColor());
}
```

You may also wish to set the background colour depending on each condition.  The reason for doing this is because the `DefaultTableCellRenderer` acts like a "rubber stamp" which is applied to each cell in turn.  If for example, the cell at row 5, column 1 has a value of k >= 0 then you are switching the foreground colour to red **for this cell and all subsequent cells**.  Therefore, it is important to **explicitly set it back** to the "normal" foreground colour if your check fails.